# Build emply OSGi bundle through Gradle

Tags: gradle, osgi

I have a `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: "osgi"

group = "aaa"
archivesBaseName = 'b.c.d'
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

def packages = [
    "com.some.package1",
    "com.some.package2"
]

jar {
     manifest {
        instruction 'Bundle-Vendor', 'Some vendor'
        instruction 'Fragment-Host', 'system.bundle;extension:=framework'
        instruction 'Export-Package', packages.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","")
    }
}
```

I want to get empty `jar` file with `MANIFEST.MF`, but:

> A Jar can only accept a valid file or directory: /my_directory/aaa/build/classes/main

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not copy MANIFEST.MF to '/my_directory/aaa/build/tmp/jar/MANIFEST.MF'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.MapFileTree$FileVisitDetailsImpl.getFile(MapFileTree.java:162)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.MapFileTree$FileVisitDetailsImpl.getSize(MapFileTree.java:222)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.FileTreeElementHasher.calculateHashForFileMetadata(FileTreeElementHasher.java:47)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultVisitedTree.calculatePreCheckHash(DefaultVisitedTree.java:89)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.VisitedTreesPreCheckHasher.calculatePreCheckHash(VisitedTreesPreCheckHasher.java:47)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter$DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotPreCheck.getHash(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.InputFilesTaskStateChanges.<init>(InputFilesTaskStateChanges.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.TaskUpToDateState.<init>(TaskUpToDateState.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:145)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:53)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A Jar can only accept a valid file or directory: /my_directory/aaa/build/classes/main
        at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar.<init>(Jar.java:58)
        at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar.<init>(Jar.java:76)
        at aQute.bnd.osgi.Analyzer.setJar(Analyzer.java:1279)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.osgi.DefaultOsgiManifest.setAnalyzerProperties(DefaultOsgiManifest.java:125)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.osgi.DefaultOsgiManifest.getEffectiveManifest(DefaultOsgiManifest.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.osgi.DefaultOsgiManifest_Decorated.getEffectiveManifest(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.osgi.DefaultOsgiManifest.getEffectiveManifest(DefaultOsgiManifest.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.java.archives.internal.DefaultManifest.writeTo(DefaultManifest.java:220)
        at org.gradle.api.java.archives.internal.DefaultManifest.writeTo(DefaultManifest.java:214)
        at org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar$1$1.execute(Jar.java:77)
        at org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar$1$1.execute(Jar.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.MapFileTree$FileVisitDetailsImpl.copyTo(MapFileTree.java:174)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyFile(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:74)
        ... 65 more
```

If I create empty class in `/my_directory/aaa/src/main/java/` it work fine. Also I can make this `jar` without `osgi` plugin, but it would be a better solution.

Comment: End up with the same scenario. Have you find any solutions for this ?

Comment: @Arundev No, I wasn't looking. It was more of an academic interest

Comment: HI Andrey - okay, thanks for the replay.

Comment: Hi @Arundev any solution for this. Stuck at same place.

Comment: @user3556411 - i leftt that comapny and forgot what i did to overcome this mate.i think endupwithmanually editing the jar file manifest.